# Working with subsets of values from single category in XGBoost

Tags: boosting, categorical-encoding, feature-engineering

Since version 1.5, XGBoost supports [categorical data](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/categorical.html) out of the box, which is a convenient way to skip the one-hot pre-processing step and allow for `if X in values` splits.

For example, given a category `animal` with values: `dog, cat, lizard, snake`, XGBoost can now split based on e.g. `if animal in {dog, cat}`, i.e. treating `animal` as a single feature, rather than using 4 "sub-features" from the one-hot encoding of `animal` and doing `if X < threshold` splits. This works for datasets like:

```
row, animal
0,   dog
1,   cat
2,   lizard
```

However, would it be possible to *extend* this to features with multiple values in the same category? That is, for datasets where the feature of a training instance is a **subset** of potential categories (multi-hot encoding)? e.g.:

```
row, animal
0,   {dog}
1,   {dog, cat}
2,   {cat, snake, lizard}
```

My intuition says no, because essentially each subset becomes a new "value", and the category now is the powerset, which becomes impractical for large cardinality. But I was wondering if there are additional tricks here.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want "cat/lizard/snake" as an extra category (probably not attractive because of many possible combinations, but perhaps an option in some cases), the standard category handling does not work for a multi-membership problem. (One-hot- or dummy-)encoding each individual category is the obvious alternative, as you note.

Alternatives include forms of embeddings that you average. E.g. one option is multi-membership target encoding. One form of this would be obtained by fitting a suitable random effects regression model with a multi-membership random effect (of course, you'd still want to do things like data splitting to avoid target leakage), but much simpler options like just calculating a target encoding for each category ignoring membership in the others and then averaging is also possible (but may not handle categories that differ substantially in prevalence all that well).